# Are there any two natural numbers a and b such that sqrt(a+b) = sqrt(a) + sqrt(b)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why is this equality impossible for ALL natural numbers a and b?

Answer (score 4):

If so, then we get by squaring $$a+b=a+b+2\sqrt{ab}$$ and we get $$\sqrt{ab}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $:$ Take square in both sides. Then you will end up with $ab=0,$ which cannot be possible if $a,b \in \Bbb N.$